# Windows phone 8.1 zoom in element in webview like browser

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1

How zoom the webview to a element (a image) ? Like double click in a element using browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `Scale` in `Composite Transform` of any `UIElement`. Check below code:

```
<Grid Height="250" Width="250">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="cmpTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

This Scale Element will help you to Zoom In and Out.

If you want to Zoom on Double Tap event then handle that event with event handler having code like below:

```
cmpTransform.ScaleX = 5;
cmpTransform.ScaleY = 5;
```

First try it yourself, and if you find any issues, mention here..!

Hope that helps..!

Comment: But i need zoom in a element inside webview ( a image inside HTML ), like browser, double tap in a image = zoom just image